# Caps-lock + num-lock + scroll-lock keylogger with window notification on linux, C

Tags: c, linux, window, keylogger

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop a few weeks ago, and it is annoying me that I cannot tell whether the caps-lock etc is on or not, because there is no light telling me on my keyboard. Windows has a popup telling me what state it is in when I press the key, but Ubuntu does not as it doesn't need it for most computers.

I want to create a sort-of keylogger that detects when one of these buttons is pressed, and has a popup in the lower centre of the screen telling me the state. The popup would be best without the window-bar-thing on the top and around the edge, but is that is too complex then I don't particularly mind. I would prefer this in C, as this seems the natural language to do this in on Linux. It would have to load on boot and preferably not have a window unless a key is pressed.

Could you explain any code posted? I would love to learn from it, as I like learning about programming languages and the libraries with them.

keys needed: Caps-Lock, Num-Lock, Scroll-Lock (not as necessary)

Comment: start here: do `xset -q | grep -i LED` on a terminal window. I believe you can find the source code for `xseq` then adapt to your needs.

Comment: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11apps/X11apps-13/xset/xset-X11R7.1-1.0.2/xset.c

Comment: `xset` has none of the needed keylogger capabilities. Actually, I'm not sure it'll be any use at all. :(

Comment: After having a look at `xset`, it doesn't seem to be of any help, and the source code is much to complex for me to change, as even though I have been programming for a while, I haven't done any C.